# Regular Expression Tweek

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

Can anyone help me get closer to the results I am trying to get?

I have this string being returned as OCR results after scanning an image:

> 7915-03226E3058-089179 Good luck for your draw on Wed 04 Sep 13 Your numbers A06 09 26 40 43 45 B 06 14 18 28 43 48 C 02 16 22 34 39 42 1111111 I I 111111111111111111111 3 plays x £1.00 for 1 draw = E 3.00 LAST WEEK, THERE WERE OVER 700,000 WINNERS ON LOTTO! 7915-032268058-089179 013779 Term. 46377201 E - •I Fill the box to void the ticket

I am attempting to pull out the values `"A06 09 26 40 43 45"`, `"B 06 14 18 28 43 48"`, and `"C 02 16 22 34 39 42"`

And to be honest, I don't need the `"A"`,`"B"`, and `"C"`. I only need the 12 numbers after each one.

I have the regex of

```
[A-Z](\W*\d{2}){6}
```

But that is pulling out extra information that I don't want as can be seen here: http://regexr.com?372b7

Can anyone suggest how to get closer? Is there a better way to try and get to the ticket numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem mainly revolves around `\W*`, this is allowing for any number (including 0) of any non word characters. So basically 111111111111 would match your capture group regex and your entire regex if preceded by a capital letter. It looks like you are wanting 2 digit pairs separated by space, you could do that like this:

```
[A-Z]\s*(\d{2}\s+){6}
```

[**Demo**](http://regexr.com?372bd)

[image]

The `\s+` makes sure there is atleast one whitespace character separating the pairs.

---

Although the above (as with the original) will only put the last pair of digits in the capture. To fix that and also ignore trailing whitespace, this could be done:

```
[A-Z]\s*(\d{2}(?:\s+\d{2}){5})
```

[**Demo**](http://regexr.com?372cn)

[image]

Note that the `(?...)` is creating a non-capture group so we can do repetitions without messing up the capture group. This will now put all 6 of the pairs of numbers into capture group 1 (which will be the only extra capture). Also, the reason for `\s*` after the `[A-Z]` is that it appears that there is optional whitespace after the leading character.

Comment: Interesting! Which tool generates this diagram?

Answer (score 2):

```
[A-Z]\s*([0-9]{2}\s+){6}
```

any uppercase letter, any number of spaces (or none), then any 2 digit number followed by one or more spaces, 6 times

Answer (score 2):

Try this. One letter, then optional spaces, then six 2-digit numbers which must have at least one space between them all, but don't have to have a space at the very end

```
[A-Z]\s*((\d{2}\s+){5}\d{2})
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?372c5)

Update:

You said you don't particularly want to retrieve the A/B/C/letter part. If your regex engine supports lookaround, you can use:

```
(?<=[A-Z]\s*)((\d{2}\s+){5}\d{2})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aRDR1imGloBbsOTE)

To only get the numbers after the letter.

Update 2: Update 1 may not work – I doubt a repeating group can be used in a lookbehind. Just use the first suggestion `[A-Z]\s*((\d{2}\s+){5}\d{2})` and capture group 1 will be the numbers you're after.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the capture group. The advantage of this solution is that it does not require a space at the very end, which the others seem to.

Comment: There is a point there I suppose if the OP's format changes in that way.